# The definition for (<*) and (*>)

Tags: haskell, applicative

Can I assume  that the below is true for all applicatives ?

```
f1 <* f2 = fmap const f1 <*> f2
```

and

```
 f1 *> f2 = fmap (flip const ) f1  <*> f2
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. From [the documentation for `Applicative`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Applicative):

> The other methods have the following default definitions, which may be overridden with equivalent specialized implementations:
>
> - `u *> v = (id <$ u) <*> v`
> - `u <* v = liftA2 const u v`

The key word there is "equivalent". Since your definitions are equivalent to those ones*, they must also be equivalent to those of all lawful Applicatives.

*If you're not convinced that your definitions are equivalent to those ones, here's some hints:

- `fmap f x = f <$> x`
- `liftA2 f x y = f <$> x <*> y`
- `flip const = const id`
- `x <$ m = const x <$> m`